# How do I get multiple scales for multiple subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, subplot

I know that to get multiple scales for a single plot you can use:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.plot(range(0,20,2))
ax2.plot(range(10))
```

However, I need to do this for four subplots.  So when I try something like:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
for row in ax:
    for col in row:
        fig1, ax1 = col.subplots()
        ax2 = ax2.twinx()
        ax1.plot(range(0,20,2)
        ax2.plot(range(10))
```

I get the error

```
'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'subplots'
```

, which makes sense, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In the code from the question, `col` would be the axes for which to create a twin axes, i.e. `ax2 = col.twinx()`.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
for row in ax:
    for col in row:
        ax2 = col.twinx()
        col.plot(range(0,20,2)
        ax2.plot(range(10))
```